# Calling stored procedure with @Query results in Exception: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ProcedureName

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an issue with calling a stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TProc1 
                            (i_cob_date IN   DATE,
                             i_location IN   VARCHAR2,
                             o_ret      OUT  VARCHAR2
                            )
AS
BEGIN
 --logic to update a table based on i_cob_date 

    o_ret := '0';
    commit;

END TProc1;
```

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "call TProc1(:i_cob_date, :i_location)", nativeQuery = true)
    String markStatus(@Param("i_cob_date")Date cobDate, @Param("i_location")String location);

}
```

I am using SpringBoot with Spring Data JPA, when i tried to invoke the method I got below error.

```
Could not extract the ResultSet
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TProc1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your stored procedure with three parameters, but you are calling it only with two in the SQL script in the `@Query` annotation.

Once that is fixed you will run in the next problem, because your script doesn't return a value. JPA wouldn't know what to return from that and therefore the same is true for Spring Data JPA. I'm not at all sure if that can be fixed with the approach you choose.

For calling stored procedures with JPA I highly recommend [declaring them using `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-stored-procedures).
You can then [access that stored procedure using Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures).